# unable to get field value from database.query method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

I am using database.query method to retrieve 2 fields from account. But when i tried to fetch get the values of that fields i am getting null value. Can someone help me.
Here totalValueFieldName is API Name of the account field.

```
  List<SObject> lstObj = Database.query(query);
            system.debug('lstObj -- '+lstObj);
            if(lstObj.size() > 0){
                Decimal totalVal = 0;
                Decimal actualVal = 0; 

                if(totalValueFieldName != null && totalValueFieldName.trim() != ''){ 
                    system.debug('totalValueFieldName top -- '+totalValueFieldName);
                    system.debug('lstObj[0].get  totalValueFieldName top -- '+lstObj[0].get(totalValueFieldName));
                    totalVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(totalValueFieldName)));

                } 
                actualVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName)));                     
                //Means only 1 API Name was supplied and field type is percentage
                if(totalVal == 0){
                    retVal = Integer.valueOf(actualVal );
                }else if (actualVal > 0){
                    retVal = Integer.valueOf( ( actualVal / totalVal ) * 100 );  
                }
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you 100% certain that the data is there? Regardless some defensive coding would be beneficial. You're getting a null pointer exception here:

`actualVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName)));`

I would check that `lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName)` is not null before calling `Decimal.valueOf()`.

Perhaps something like this:

`if(String.isNotEmpty(lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName))) {
   actualVal = Decimal.valueOf(String.valueOf(lstObj[0].get(actualValueFieldName)));
}`

Comment: Thank you @Mathew McKenzie.  It worked. Data for that record was not there..